# IFrameResizer issue

Tags: html, iframe, iframe-resizer

I'm using IFrameResizer to be able to bring to full page without scollbar an iframe. With the following code I don't get the desired result. What should I correct?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en"> <head> <meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"> <title>TEST ROCKETMAN</title> <style>
<script src="iframeResizer.js" > </script >
</head >
<body >
<style>iframe{width:100%}</style>
<iframe src="https://cdn.rocketman.elbet.com/?uid=bruce&version=desktop&language=en&companyId=1&currency=eur" name="' + Date.now() + '" width="100%" height="100%" scrolling="no"></iframe>
<script>iFrameResize({log:true})</script>
</body >
</html >
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to add style for your iframe

```
style="overflow:hidden;height:100vh;width:100%"
```

It will change the height of the iframe. [*vh is viewport height*]

if you have scrollbars reduce the height according to your page content.